# Cannot find Auto Fix On Save button in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

I was following tutorial to turn on ESLint Auto Fix on saving a file. Tutorial demonstrates to check a checkbox. And I cannot find it. Do I need any extension or smth?

Go to: View -> command pallete -> Preferences: Open Workspace Settings -> Extensions -> ESLint

This is how settings page look like in tutorial:

[image: How settings page should look]

this is what I see:

[image: This is what I see]

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The setting is deprecated. Auto Fix on Save is now part of VS Code's Code Action on Save infrastructure. See the [release notes](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint#release-notes). Just for fun you can bring the checkbox back by adding `"eslint.autoFixOnSave": true` to your *settings.json*. However, what you need to add now instead is:

```
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
  }
```

Comment: Thank you it helped :) For those who cannot find their settings.json file:
Go to: File -> Preferences -> Settings -> ESLint. There you willl se "Edit in settings.json". (it is visible in printscreen I provided before)

Answer (score 6):

```sh
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
}
```

Since VSCode 1.56, this solution only works when you trigger save action manually by Ctrl/Cmd + S.
It won't work with auto save with `onFocusChange` or `onWindowChange`.

In my case, I wanna trigger eslint anytime my code saved. So instead of using `editor.codeActionsOnSave`, I set eslint as the default formatter for js/ts, then trigger format on save.

```
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"
},
"[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"
},
"eslint.format.enable": true,
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
```

Answer (score 1):

Previously, you could not set Code Actions on Save to work with AutoSave.  This has been fixed in the latest v1.83 Stable.

From [v1.83 Release Notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_83#_code-actions-on-save-and-auto-save)

> ##### Code Actions on Save and Auto Save
>
> You can now enable Code Actions on Auto Save in the editor. This
> triggers Code Actions when you save or Auto Save with window change
> (`onWindowChange`) or focus change (`onFocusChange`). To enable this
> feature or update your current settings, check Editor: Code Actions On
> Save (`editor.codeActionsOnSave`) and change each Code Action's
> setting to `always`.
>
> The setting values were also updated, with the current boolean values
> to be deprecated in favor of the string equivalent.
>
> The options are:

`explicit`: Triggers Code Actions when explicitly saved. Same as
`true`.
`always`: Triggers Code Actions when explicitly saved and on
Auto Saves from window or focus changes.
`never`: Never triggers
Code Actions on save. Same as `false`.

> Boolean values are still supported in this release.

Go to this setting:

```
Editor: Code Actions on Save
```

and click on the `Edit in settings.json` link therein.

In order to get the code action to work on BOTH manual and auto-saves you would create a setting like:

```json
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": "always"       // use always for both manual and auto saves
  }
```